# Arduino store variable by serial read rfid

Tags: variables, serial-port, arduino, rfid

I want to store the same that is displayed in the Serial Monitor in a variable, because after that i can send the value to a Database.
That's the code:

```
if (bytesread == 12) {  
 for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    if (code[i] < 16) Serial.print("0");
       Serial.print(code[i], HEX);
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
```

Is Displayed at Serial Monitor the tag that i scan:

```
04007E4985
```

I want to store the tag value in a variable like:

```
    tag = code[i];
```

Some sugestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of char an put it:

```
char theCode[5];
if (bytesread == 12) {  
   for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
     if (code[i] < 16) Serial.print("0");
     // Serial.print(code[i], HEX); 
     theCode[i] = code[i];
   }
     Serial.println(theCode);
}
```